# LocalStorage not working on iPad and iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, html, local-storage

I'm having troubles with HTML5 LocalStorage on my iPad and iPhone.  I've developed a HTML5/CSS3/JavaScript (jQuery/jQuery Mobile) website and I'm trying to store a couple of pieces of data to LocalStorage (just a couple of small strings).

When I navigate to the website on either the iPad or the iPhone by simply opening Safari and typing in the URL, I get notification from Moderizr that localstorage is not supported, and, thus, my values are not saved on the device.

However, if I use the Save to Home Screen option, save an icon/link to my mobile website on the Home Screen, close "regular" Safari, and open the application using the Home Screen icon, Moderizr tells me localstorage is available, and my values are written and read as expected.

So, I'm confused.  Why does it work after saving the link to the Home Screen but it doesn't work if I type the URL directly in Safari?  Is there some trick I'm missing to make it work in both scenarios?

I've tried with both iOS 5.1.1 and 6.  And, my settings are the basic defaults.

Thanks.

Comment: Anyone?  I'm still unable to get my mobile web site to save cookies or local storage to the device (iPad and iPhone) when running from inside mobile Safari.  But, it appears to work if I save to home screen and open the mobile web site that way.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

After many headaches, I think I got it figured out.  HTML5 local storage and private browsing do not mix.  I had private browsing on (in the Safari settings) and that appeared to be blocking local storage.  Actually, an exception was being thrown but swallowed up by the browser (???).  Once I turned private browsing off, everything appeared to work.

Comment: 4 years later and it's still an issue. How strange. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Still in Nov. 2016. (if anyone wandering)

Comment: still in Dec, 2016.

Comment: still in Jan 2017

Comment: still in March 2017

Comment: It was no issue in februari 2017

Comment: Still an issue in May 2017 (Safari 7, iOS 7.1.2)

Comment: Still an issue in June 2017 iPhone iOS 10

Comment: Are we talking about simply closing all private tabs or is there any special settings? i am on iOS 11 Developer beta 7 and having this issue on safari and chrome both on my iPhone.

Comment: still in November 30 2017 5 years and ...

Comment: March 2018 Update here, still not working, water is running low, send help

Comment: same here, march 2018

Comment: I would suspect that is by design. You can possibly use sessionStorage in place of localStorage though?

Comment: This is definitely a browser design.